# how can i recreate a font .ttf of an old typewriter from a scanned document?

Tags: windows-7

I have a scanned document of an old typewriter and i want to extract it and create a windows font so as to have it on my computer. I have tried creating the font using font creator from scratch by joining different fonts but it does not look exactly as the typewriter font.

Comment: Does nothing on Google help? https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=create+font+from+a+scan

Answer (score 0):

After scanning the image of your letters and numbers, you need to use a image manipulation program, such as Photoshop, to get each letter in vector format. This is where you would adjust spacing and dimensions of each letter.

After exporting the vector images, you must use a font compiler program. There are a few paid and free ones out there, the one I used in the past has been [Fontstruct](http://fontstruct.com/).

Honestly, this is process used by many font-creators to do their work, anyway.

Comment: thanks, let me get photoshop and change to vector format.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't using a free generic typewriter font a better option in this case?

[http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=113&l=10&l=1](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=113&l%5B%5D=10&l%5B%5D=1)

Comment: that exact typewriter font is needed so as to shift from using the typewriter to using computers. the font can not be changed.